# Android platform, can I meet those requirements?

Tags: android

Folks, I'm trying to see if my plan realistic at all. I'm ne to
Android platform but not new to software development. This is my first
post here as well :)

We want (in our company) to create Android software to compliment our
truck management software. Basically, it will do couple very specific
tasks.

a. Send GPS updates to server.
b. Receive trip information.
c. Send pickup/delivery confirmation to server.

After evaluationg i. platform and Windows phone 7 platform we came to
conclusion that only Android has multitasking that works for us. So,
Android it is but I have some specific questions.

1. Data plan we want to use will be very limited. Probably 5M/mo and
   no voice/text. I figured 5x1024x1024 = 5242280 bytes will give me 1k
   per transmission every 15 minutes (3000 transmissions per mo). It will
   leave 2M for other stuff that will happens every couple of days. Does
   my math look OK or there is lot of "waste" traffic? Our server going
   to be XML SOAP and messages sent will be just Lon/Lat in XML package.
   1K will be OK? If I just calculate bytes it will be even less but I
   wonder if there is "minimum" packet size, etc. Any insight on this
   data limitation appreciated.
2. Because of #1 we need to "lock" device somehow so there is no other
   software that uses network. Possible? If so, what do I need to look
   for? I found already created app - firewall and it says phone has to
   be rooted for that.
3. Receiving trip information. What's the best way to accomplish that
   given my situation? Should I run some kind of listener? Will my phone
   have IP address or something? Or should I get small text plan and use
   that for this specific functionality? Can I receive text message in my
   own application?

So, as you see we trying to shrink $80/mo service to $15/mo service
that will do big savings to our company but not sure if it's all
possible with constraints we have. Also, we may just give discounts to
drivers who have Android phone and will install our app but we don't
count on that.

Thank you in advance for any help on this subject.

**UPDATE**:
Now that I think about it - limited data plan present challenges initially but actually helps us do it "right" to make sure we don't overload server with constant polls. What I really like to see is some real-worls experience with data usage. Problem is, to us to even come up with test app - will require considerable effort. Would be much better to rule this out right now if it won't work. For example, if I knew that message size 2k no matter how big of a message itslef - then I would know immediately that it won't work for us..

Comment: 1. create a few request/response with the device and you will know if 5M will be enough
2. either rooted phone or a custom system image
3. if you need frequent updates from a server you will have to ask the server about them frequently

Comment: As far as pushing updates - asking server is no good(data limitation) - but I can use SMS for that or even better Google already got http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/

Comment: the c2dm sounds good but it says "Note: Android C2DM will ultimately be available to all developers. However, it is currently launched in Labs, and not universally available. If you're interested in using C2DM with your Android applications, go to the signup page to request access. Google will contact you when you've been granted access." , SMS would be harder because you will need a SMS gateway to send them from the server

Comment: Ah, but SMS gateway is easy (though not free)

Comment: I checked prices - SMS is very affordable and we can use it to send data, not to ask for server poll. $150 for 5000 messages will go long way. Basically, it will serve 2-3k trips or so..

Comment: Look very carefully at the data that you MUST send.  2K/message seems like a lot.  Especially if you're sending this much every 15 minutes - how fast do your drivers work anyway ;)

Comment: @katit ok then it sounds like a solution

Comment: @KevinDTimm probably they want to send real-time GPS position of the drivers, to check if they are using the scheduled route and so on (if it is once per hour, the driver can go for a burger in the meanwhile :) )

Comment: @katit sorry but I keep thinking that SMS is a bad option. For example, you DON'T know when the specs will change and you will have to upload something extra like a cargo ID etc, so if you go after the 160 chars (for 7-bit encoding) the SMS will double, so it would be 150$ for 2.5k, after a while it can triple and so on

Comment: @apps - gps is tiny, only some kind of id, lat/lon necessary (he says every 15 minutes, but even every 5 minutes it's pretty small 12/hr * 8 hrs is 96 messages/day * 50 bytes max).  Note too that he can use the sms to trigger the app (as opposed to polling)

Comment: GPS updates every 15 minutes OK with us, no need for more than that. I will even write it with throttling so if I don't see movement I won't update server. We can work with things like that. SMS - Agree, it's not good solution but it can be interim solution until google releases it's cloud service. But again, how it google's service going to work? If it's going to do pooling on background it's no good for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a very limited kind of data that you are transferring, the overhead of xml might be unnecessary.  Instead, pass .csv data to different endpoints dependent upon the data that your are transfering (one endpoint for lat/lon, another for pickup/delivery confirmation)

You do have an ip address on each device, but you're not necessarily going to know that information - it's not constant, or consistent (it can change as the phone moves around).  <strike>Instead, do a timed polling of the server (that would make your 3rd endpoint)</strike>  See other mentioned solution of triggering on SMS.

As far as locking the device, I'm not sure about this, but it certainly seems feasible (though it's not consistent with your 'discounts to drivers who have Android phone'.  I understand why, but if the phone has no voice/text capability, it's not likely that the phone will be used by the drivers for much besides it's expected purpose.

Comment: Well, we plan to give out devices with all prepaid minimal data only plan. For drivers that will have plan - we can just do discount and install app. Driver-owned phones will not have limitations, they most likely going to be unlimited data plans.

The way I see it - "free" phones will need to be rooted, data access locked and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to achieve this with a default Android ROM in other words you have to create your own customized ROM from scratch and deactivate quite some stuff in order to get your devices not to use up the 5M/Month.

You can checkout the developers site on the [Android source code](http://source.android.com/) to check out if that would be an option for you. Giving discounts to drivers owning an Android phone sounds nice and all but I'm quite certain that this is not going to get the desired results which I guess are that you equip all your trucks with such a device and track all of them.

In my opinion it is not going to work with a data plan of 5M/Month but on the other hand I don't know the data consumption numbers without testing.

UPDATE: Also I would not go with XML but with JSON due to overhead.

Comment: I think that should do it for controlling OS?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/droidwall/

I don't think creating customized ROM is and option.

Comment: to use the Linux iptables you need a super user permission

Comment: Yes, that's OK. We will be giving those phones out so we can do whatever we need to do with them

Comment: @katit OK, but note that if they have a GUI app for that, they could remove the iptables settings. Not that this is important since they will use it for work and they are not gaining anything with wasting their traffic, but still

Comment: DroidWall app has password functionality. But this is not something I'm really concerned about.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload a GPS update, have the server reply with any of the trip data you need to push down to the phone at that time.

Comment: This might work if I will be able to shrink time to 5min. Otherwise - 15 minutes is too long.

Comment: I doubt the payload of a packed GPS update will significantly increase your data consumption over an empty poll of the server, so you might as well.

Comment: note he doesn't have to poll, a pushed SMS makes it unnecessary

Comment: I was under the impression that the phones would be on plans not offering SMS reception capability.  If that isn't the case - even if charged 20 centers per received - then this would work.

Answer (score -1):

I think that for the data traffic (the other topics that you asked about are already solved in the other answers) using a bitmask-like solution will be the best option, first bits are for lat, the next for lon, and then some bitmask for the flags, and sending text data only if it is necessary.

Comment: Yes, it's all sounds good but I wonder if there any overhead in data traffic? Like I mentioned, we may count bytes but package size will be 1k at minimum and that's it..

Comment: @katit you can send the gps data in bits, and when you are close to the 5M limit you can switch to SMS. This is also the hardest to implement solution, but the easiest one is with XML/JSON with which you disagree, so probably this one will works out best for you

Comment: I didn't say I disagree with JSON. Our shop is primarily Microsoft, so server going to be running IIS/Web Service. Ideally it will be soap calls. If I count bytes in SOAP message we should be set. I just worry that there going to be overhead. This question can be answered only with experience I think. Until we test we won't know. Good thing it that there is other solutions out there that do that with listed data plan so network allows it for sure.

Comment: and I doubt that with interval of 15 minutes to update you will reach 5 MB per month

Comment: then we can update once in 5 minutes but that is not really needed :) We can also slow down updates to once/hr if there is no movement. Lot's of possibilities. I guess it's sounds feasible to do the project. See ho we started conversation that 5mb is no good :)

Comment: well you counted that 5 MB is no good for text data, the lat/lon in doubles are 64 bits each, and 1 char for text is 16 bits, so with a bitmask this calc is wrong. anyway, I see that the question is solved and you don't need anymore thinking on it, it was an interesting one :)

Comment: Seeng others doing it - I think it should be working. My only question that still unresolved is when I send 50bytes does it count as 50 bytes by provider? If so - that's cool.

Comment: @katit it depends on whether you counted the headers of the HTTP in your calculations too

Comment: The way I see it - whole message (with headers) can be fit into 256 bytes.

Comment: I think that too, but you have to listen to the packages to make sure. Also, I didn't actually answer your question if the other tcp/ip packages are calculated as traffic too, which I don't know, you have to google it (maybe it depends on the carrier??)

Comment: Google didn't help.. I guess at this point Action is pretty clear
1. Root and install iptables
2. Write sample APP to message server 3k times.
3. Check what provider says :)